# how to create a styling in button in flutter?

Tags: flutter, user-interface, dart

How make this styling for a button in flutter. Since I'm a newbie, I have no Idea on how to do it.

In image the triangle is somewhat irregular, I want that to be matched with the button box.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [CustomPaint](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/CustomPaint-class.html) widget to get that effect. You can easily auto-generate the CustomPaint code from [Flutter Shape Maker](https://fluttershapemaker.com/). Please see the code below. You can also run the code on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/0171e4b838b740ea23f896f3b0be1f8e) at the following URL https://dartpad.dev/0171e4b838b740ea23f896f3b0be1f8e :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: MyWidget(),
    );
  }
}

class MyWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          width: 360,
          height: 100,
          color: Colors.black,
          child: CustomPaint(
            size: Size(1200, 700),
            painter: FlagPainter(),
            child: Text(
              "text",
              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize:24),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FlagPainter extends CustomPainter {
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint_0 = new Paint()
      ..color = Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255)
      ..style = PaintingStyle.fill
      ..strokeWidth = 1;

    Path path_0 = Path();
    path_0.moveTo(0, 0);
    path_0.lineTo(0, size.height * 2.40);
    path_0.lineTo(0, size.height * 0.72);
    path_0.lineTo(size.width * 0.28, 0);

    canvas.drawPath(path_0, paint_0);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(covariant CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please can you explain the FlagPainter Code. Please It would be helpful for me.

Comment: Please see this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kp14Y4uHpHs Widget of the Week video from Flutter Team to understand CustomPaint. FlagPainter is really very easy. The black container is the canvas on which the CustomPaint draws. First the paint is created with color white, paint style fill and stroke width of 1. The Path is created. Path begins at top left which is 0, then the flag shape or triangle shape is created by drawing lines. The the path is closed. I recommend you see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z4-XLVRCRpA to understand CustomPaint.

Comment: Also see this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxhneengTl0 which shows how to use Flutter Shape Maker https://fluttershapemaker.com/